# Space of continuous functions with mapping to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support are dense in $F(X,\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have the following statements

At first, theorem 1:
Let
$A$ be a complete metric space,
$B$ a separable metric space,
$M$ in $A\times B$ open and dense set, then

the room $A$ contains a dense set $N$ with the property, that for every point $a$ of $N$ in $B$ exists a dense set of points $y$, such that all points $(a,y)$ belongs to $M$. End theorem 1.

Let $F_n(X):=\{f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \;|\;f\;continuous \}$ the space of continuous functions with mapping to $\mathbb{R}^n$ on a compact metric space $X$ provided with sup-metric and
$G_n(X):=\{f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \;|\; f\; continuous,\; f(r)\neq 0, \; \forall \; x\in X\}$ the space of continuous functions with mapping to $\mathbb{R}^n$ without functions with zeros, on a compact metric space $X$ provided with sup-metric.

So $F_n(X)$ is a complete, separable metric space, $G_n(X)$ is open in $F_n(X)$ and we can write $F_n(X)$ as $F_1(X)\times F_{n-1}(X)$.

So if $G_n(X)$ is dense in $F_n(X)$ we can use theorem 1.
Therefore there exists a everywhere dense of functions $f\in F_1(X)$ such that:
a) For all functions $\varphi\in F_{n-1}$ who combined with $f$ yield an element $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$, form a dense set in $F_{n-1}$

If we define for $f\in F_1(X)$ with $E(f)$ as set of points $x\in X$ with $f(x)=0$, then for $\varphi\in F_{n-1}$ is the relation $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$ equivalent, that no point of $E(f)$ will be mapped through $\varphi$ in the point $(0,0,\ldots, 0)\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

I don't understand why $\varphi(x)$ with $x\in E(f)$ can't be mapped to the zero vector. 
Because, let us start with $F_1(X)\times F_1(X)$. Have a look a my picture (sorry for ugly writing). [Visualisation of my imagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG2HI.jpg)

so if we take one constant $f$ in $G_2(X)$ e.g. $f(x)=1$, then $\varphi$ can be mapped to $0$ in $G_2$ (because the constraint that functions with zeros in $G_2$ are not allowed are not broken) and therefore it is allowed to use $\varphi(x)$ with $x\in E(f)$ if $f$ is not a function with zero.

Can anyone help me to find my logic mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore there exists a everywhere dense of functions $f\in F_1(X)$ such that:
>   a) For all functions $\varphi\in F_{n-1}$ who combined with $f$ yield an element $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$, form a dense set in $F_{n-1}$

That is there exists a dense set $N$ of $F_1(x)$ such that for each $f\in N$ the set  $G_f=\{\varphi\in F_{n-1}(X):(f,\varphi)\in G_{n}(X)\}$ is dense. Note that the set $G_f$ depends on the function $f$ and it may be not the same for distinct $f\in F_1(X)$.

> If we define for $f\in F_1(X)$ with $E(f)$ as set of points $x\in X$ with $f(x)=0$, then for $\varphi\in F_{n-1}$ is the relation $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$ equivalent, that no point of $E(f)$ will be mapped through $\varphi$ in the point $(0,0,\ldots, 0)\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Right.

> I don't understand why $\varphi(x)$ with $x\in E(f)$ can't be mapped to the zero vector.

Note, that we still speak about pairs $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$. And if $x\in E(f)$ and $\varphi(x)=0$ then $(f(x),\varphi(x))=0$, which contradicts $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$.

> so if we take one constant $f$ in $G_2(X)$ e.g. $f(x)=1$, then $\varphi$ can be mapped to $0$ in $G_2$ (because the constraint that functions with zeros in $G_2$ are not allowed are not broken) and therefore it is allowed to use $\varphi(x)$ with $x\in E(f)$ if $f$ is not a function with zero.

We are allowed to use $\varphi$ means $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$ for a given fixed $f$. This doesn’t imply that we are allowed to use $\varphi$ with a different function, say $f’\in F_1(X)$. For a particular choice of $f$, when $f(x)=1$ for each $x\in X$, a set $E(f)=\{x\in X :f(x)=0\}$ is empty. Then $G_f=\{\varphi\in F_{n-1}(X):(f,\varphi)\in G_{n}(X)\}=F_{n-1}(X)$. But this does not mean that $G_{f’}=F_{n-1}(X)$ for any function $f’\in F_1(X).$

Remark that in this case also $E(f)=\{x\in X :f(x)=0\}$ is empty, so we cannot "use $\varphi(x)$ with $x\in E(f)$", because there is no such $x$.  But if $f’\in F_1(X)$ is an other function then we are allowed to use a function $\varphi\in F_{n-1}$ *with the function $f’$*, that is $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$ iff  $\varphi(x)\ne 0$ for each $x\in E(f’)$.

PS. It seems that the picture is not needed.

Comment: And what about if only one $f$ is constant e.g. $f=1$ and the other have zeros. So one can write $(1,\varphi)$ with $\varphi$ abitrary. Then it did not contradicts $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$?

Comment: @GeoRie Looking for $(f,\varphi)\in G_n(X)$, we cannot pair arbitrary $f$ with arbitrary $\varphi$, we need a restriction $\varphi(x)\ne(0,0,\dots,0)\in\Bbb R^{n-1}$ for each $x\in E(f)$, right?

Comment: Yes. That's my question. Why we need a restriction to $\varphi$ if we combine it with those $f$ who did not have zeros. Then we don't need a restriction for $\varphi$? Thrn, if we choose such $f$, $\varphi$ can be mapped to zero in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Do you understand my thoughts? Are my thoughts wrong? Could you explain it more exact, please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GeoRie I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you answer a last question, please? Why then we can say that $G_{n-1}(E(f))$ is dense in $F_{n-1}(E(f))$? It is clear that $\{\varphi(x)|\; x\in E(f)\}=:G_{n-1}(E(f))\subset F_{n-1}(E(f))$. But why (with consideration of tietze extension theorem) is it dense? Because $E(f)$ is closed in $X$ because $X$ is a $T_2$-room and therefore with tietze $G_{n-1}(E(f))=G_{n-1}(X)$ and $F_{n-1}(E(f))=F_{n-1}(X)$ and because $G_{n-1}(X)$ is dense in $F_{n-1}(X)$ (because of induction assumption) $G_{n-1}(E(f))$ is dense in $F_{n-1}(E(f))$? Thanks

Comment: sorry, because of the condition $G_{n}(X)$ is dense in $F_{n}(X)$ not because of induction assumption.

Comment: @GeoRie I did not perfectly understand the point of your comment. For instance, we have a problem to equal $G_{n−1}(E(f))$ and $G_{n−1}(X)$, because functions from these sets, have, in general, different domains. Tietze extension theorem implies that a restriction map $r_f: F_{n−1}(X)\to F_{n−1}(E(f))$, $\varphi\mapsto \varphi|E(f)$ is surjective. But by the [drum theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120877/the-drum-theorem-in-topology), in general, $r_f(G_{n−1}(X))\ne G_{n−1}(E(f))$. Concerning the notation from my answer, $G_f=r_f^{-1}(G_{n−1}(E(f)))$ for each $f\in F_1(X)$.

Comment: Also I remark that whether $G_n(X)$ is dense in $F_n(X)$ depends on $X$. For instance, an answer is negative when $n=1$ and $X$ is connected. Again the drum theorem suggests a negative answer when  $n\ge 2$ and $X=[0,1]^m$ with $n\ge m$.